# Merging a "read-only" partition into the main partition

Tags: lubuntu, gparted, disk-usage

I have tried to enlarge my lubuntu 20.04 disk size, which is being run within VirtualBox.

This created a second device `/dev/sda1` which I can see but I cannot access.

When I run `sudo sfdisk -luS` I see:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 16 GiB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x56d7e4ab

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 33543719 33541672  16G 83 Linux
```

When I run `sudo parted -l` I see:

```
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 17,2GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  17,2GB  17,2GB  primary  ext4


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr1 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr1
has been opened read-only.
Error: /dev/sr1: unrecognised disk label
Model: Unknown (unknown)                                                  
Disk /dev/sr1: 60,6MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: unknown                                                         
Disk Flags:
```

When I run `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL` I see:

```
$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME   FSTYPE     SIZE MOUNTPOINT                      LABEL
loop0  squashfs  97,8M /snap/core/10185                
loop1  squashfs  97,9M /snap/core/10583                
loop2  squashfs  55,4M /snap/core18/1932               
loop3  squashfs  55,4M /snap/core18/1944               
loop4  squashfs 162,9M /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145       
loop5  squashfs  62,1M /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506    
loop6  squashfs  64,8M /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514    
loop7  squashfs     4M /snap/notepad-plus-plus/238     
loop8  squashfs   5,5M /snap/notepad-plus-plus/253     
loop9  squashfs   145M /snap/notepadqq/855             
loop10 squashfs    31M /snap/snapd/9721                
loop11 squashfs 303,1M /snap/wine-platform-5-stable/16 
loop12 squashfs  31,1M /snap/snapd/10707               
loop13 squashfs 231,5M /snap/wine-platform-runtime/188 
loop14 squashfs 215,5M /snap/wine-platform-5-stable/12 
loop15 squashfs 337,8M /snap/wine-platform-runtime/206 
sda                16G                                 
└─sda1 ext4        16G /                               
sr0              1024M                                 
sr1    iso9660   57,8M /media/myUsername/VBox_GAs_6.1.12     VBox_GAs_6.1.12
```

When I open GParted (either within the guest OS, or by booting into it with GParted Live) I cannot see `/dev/sda1`.

How can I merge this new partition and gain access to the additional disk space?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`? This might provide some additional information that can help someone provide a specific answer to the question 

Comment: @Matigo sure thing - added!

Comment: How did you expand the disk in VirtualBox ? What was the size before, and how much  / to what did you enlarge it  ? Also, /dev/sda1 is not a new partition. it is where your filesystem lives (└─sda1 ext4        16G /   ).

Comment: The "second device" remark does not line up with your `lsblk` information. Could you take a screenshot of your VirtualBox storage settings and share that? This will make things much clearer. It *sounds* like you have simply expanded your existing storage file, and you just need to grow that volume to fill the new space. It would be good to confirm this *before* writing an answer, though.

Comment: @Matigo sure thing! It's here: https://i.imgur.com/5wkhMZo.png Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: @SorenA On the windows command line I used `VBoxManage modifymedium disk lubuntu.vdi --resize 32768`. I doubled its size.

Comment: @Matigo do you happen to have any advice for me?

Answer (score 3):

With the information that you've provided via edits and comments, it's easy to see that you've expanded your VirtualBox .vdi correctly and Ubuntu recognizes the full size. Now to make use of it.

In order to expand your current partition to use the full 32GB, you will need to have an Ubuntu Desktop `.iso` file. If you don't already have one available, [download a copy from the Ubuntu website](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Any version will do, though it would probably be best to grab the most recent version.

#### Background

For the sake of this walk-through, I've created a VirtualBox VM of Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 with a 25GB primary partition. I then resized the partition on the host using the following command:

```
VBoxManage modifymedium disk "Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.vdi" --resize 51200
```

[image: VirtualBox Storage Settings]

Aside from the size of the partition, these are the same steps you did to create and later expand your VM storage size. After booting into the VM, I opened GParted and looked at the partition information for the main storage device, `/dev/sda`:

[image: GParted - Primary Partition]

This is likely where you are in the process.

#### Resizing the Partition

It is not possible to resize a partition if it is currently mounted, and we cannot unmount a partition that is used for the operating system itself. For this reason, we need to boot into the "Live DVD" environment offered by the Ubuntu Desktop `.iso` file. Shut down the VM and add the `.iso` to the virtual optical drive for the VM:

[image: VirtualBox - Optical Device Settings]

Before booting the VM, double-check the device boot sequence. The optical drive must be placed ahead of the storage device. Once confirmed, boot the VM. You *may* see a file system check take place during boot. Let it complete:

[image: File System Check]

You will be presented with the option to "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu". As you already have a working installation, you will want to select "Try Ubuntu". This will start up a live environment from which you can modify your partitions.

Once the system finishes loading the live environment, open the "Disks" application. This will present information on your storage device(s) and the partitions contained within:

[image: Disks - Examining the Partitions]

Click on the top square that reads "Extended Partition", then click the gears icon and choose "Resize...". You will be shown an option to modify the size of the partition with a slider. Extend the partition all the way to the end (if you would like to use the entire storage medium):

[image: Disks - Extend the Extended Partition]

***IMPORTANT:** While you can click on the lower partition square and then choose to resize, you cannot extend the partition beyond the size of the upper square — even though the UI makes it look like you can. Any changes you make to extend the size of the formatted partition will be silently ignored. Start with the top square.*

Click "Resize" and give the system a few minutes to do the work of expanding the extended partition. You will see the partition map updated to look something like this:

[image: Disks - Let it Grow]

Now you can do the same for the actual data partition:

[image: Resize]

Then:

[image: Grow that Partition]

You should now see that the data partition is properly resized:

[image: All done]

You can confirm this is complete by opening GParted and seeing a second application report the same numbers:

[image: GParted Says ...]

***Optional:** Consider running a "Check Filesystem" just to ensure that everything is 100% before leaving the Live DVD environment.*

[image: Disks - Check File System]

Now shut down the VM, remove the `.iso` image from the virtual optical drive, and boot into your proper environment. Once logged in, confirm that the partitions are the correct size with GParted and/or `df`:

[image: Confirmation]

There are a lot of steps here but, when you follow them one by one, you'll see this process is not at all complicated. What's more, VirtualBox will allow you to incrementally grow your partitions up to 2TB in total. That means you can become quite expert at this process in the future if you are regularly resizing your partitions.

I hope this is the "advice" you were looking for.

Comment: You are the best person alive for creating this helpful guide for me. Thank you so much. Unfortunately I am running into a problem in one of the steps. I cannot see the extra 16 GB that I freed up when I open Disks: https://i.imgur.com/DlH5bLU.png Do you have any idea what might be going wrong?